# Percentage of failed devices.

Tags: probability

According to one of the Western Electric rules for quality control, a produced item is
considered conforming if its measurement falls within three standard deviations from the
target value. Suppose that the process is in control so that the expected value of each
measurement equals the target value. What percent of items will be considered conforming,
if the distribution of measurements is

(a) Normal($u, \sigma$)?

(b) Uniform(a, b)?

Please hint me.

---

Answer (score 1):

For the case $X \sim Norm(\mu, \sigma),$ you want
$$P\{-3\sigma \le (X - \mu) \le 3\sigma\}.$$
Standardize and use normal tables. The answer is near 100%.
Draw a sketch.

For $Y \sim Univ(a,b)$, you have no tables, but finding
probabilities from a sketch of the density function is
trivial (areas of rectangles). Note that $\mu = E(Y) = (a+b)/2$,
the midpoint of the interval that contains all of the probability.
Also, $\sigma^2 = (b-a)^2/12$, and take the square root 
to get $\sigma$.

I don't know whether you are expected to
use simple calculus to get $\mu$ and $\sigma^2,$ of whether
this information is given in your book.

If you're having trouble drawing a sketch here, start with
a specific example, maybe let $a = 1$ and $b=3$. Hint: The
uniform has no "tails."

I'll check later today to see whether you accepted this answer
of left a comment asking for clarification.